# select2 add custom classes using processResults

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I used to add custom classes and use it to fill an input according to the selection
since I did it directly in the view

example:

```
<option value="290044" data-nombre="xxxx" data-select2-id="20">0931105/Diego Suarez</option>
```

but since I had to bring more than 70000 records I do it now from the server side and I don't know how to add the custom classes that I want to appear
it appears like this automatically

example

```
    <option value="290044" (here i want to add my custom class) data-select2-id="20">09311055/Diego Suarez</option>
```

I attach the complete code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
$("#cliente").select2({
    language: "es",
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
      url: "/Clientes/jsonclientes",
      dataType: "json",
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
              text: item.NIF20 + "/" + item.NOMBRECLIENTE,
              id: item.CODCLIENTE,
            };
          }),
        };
      },
      cache: true,
    },
  });
$("#cliente").change(function () {
    let selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    direccion = selected.data("direccion");
    $("#direccione").val(direccion);
  });
    })
```